# JSR223 Timer in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

How to create thread delay in seconds based on the calculation(duration/throughput) using JSR223 Timer. what should I write inside the script section ?We are having the Duration and throughput as Jmeter parameters in our Test Plan

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) - both can be configured with combination of the desired throughput and test duration. The timers are smart enough in order to pause JMeter threads to reach the needed throughput.

---

If for some reason the above timers are not suitable you can consider implementing so called [Pacing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter) - a dynamic delay between Thread Group iterations.

The example code would be something like:

```
//Sets the pacing length based on the last requests response time. 4500 is the time in ms
Long pacing = 4500 - prev.getTime();

//If the response time is less than 4500 ms, set the delay value to myDelay
if ( pacing > 0 )
{
    //iPacing is equal to the int value of pacing if pacing is not equal to null, otherwise iPacing is null
    Integer iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null;
    log.info(String.valueOf(iPacing));
    vars.put("myDelay", String.valueOf(iPacing));
    return iPacing;
}
//The response time is greater than or equal to 4500 ms, set myDelay to 0
else
{
    vars.put("myDelay", "0");
    return 0;
}
```